# How to pass component value to Custom Directive Host Listener in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to pass model value from my HTML template to my custom directive:

```
    @Directive({
    selector: '[eventlistener]'
})
export class EventListener {
  @Input() value:string = 'Not Defined';
    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
        console.log('You clicked me',value);
    }
}
```

and in my HTML template :

```
<button eventlistener (click)="captureClickEvent()" value="model.EmailAddress">test</button>
```

Currently, it's displaying model.EmailAddress, I want to get the evaluated value(which I get in the component). Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [] binding for value

```
<button eventlistener (click)="captureClickEvent()" [value]="model.EmailAddress">test</button>
```

and in onClick method use this.value instead of just value

```
@HostListener('click')
onClick() {
    console.log('You clicked me', this.value);
}
```

Comment: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'button' i am getting this error

Comment: The type doesn't really matter, just change the type on value and insure the type coming in matches.

Answer (score 0):

I just used {{model.EmailAddress}} and it worked.

```
<button eventlistener (click)="captureClickEvent()" value="{{model.EmailAddress}}">test</button>
```